# Is it possible to have two cktext_area in one form for one row rails 3 globalize3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor, globalize3

Does anyone know is it possible to have two cktext_area in one form for one row (for example description)? My rails app have two versions: english and russia. I'm using globalize3 gem and batch_translation. So in my form view i want to give administrator possibility to fill description text area for two versions. I'm using ckeditor and i can't figure out how to write two cktext_areas. If i make like this:

```
    <div class="ru-version" id="ru-version"> <%# move russian version to the partial like english version %>
        <div class="field titleField">
            <%= f.label :title, "Заголовок" %>
            <%= f.text_field :title %>
        </div>
        <div class="field textField">
            <%= f.label :description, "Краткое описание" %>
            <%= cktext_area :conference, :description, :input_html => { :toolbar => 'Easy' } %>
        </div>
        <div class="field textField">
            <%= f.label :content, "Текст" %>
            <%= cktext_area :conference, :content, :input_html => { :toolbar => 'Easy' } %>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="en-version" id="en-version">
        <%= f.globalize_fields_for :en do |builder| %>
            <div class="field titleField">
                <%= f.label :title, "Заголовок" %>
                <%= f.text_field :title %>
            </div>
            <div class="field textField">
                <%= f.label :description, "Краткое описание" %>
                <%= f.text_area :description %>
                <%= cktext_area :conference, :description, :input_html => { :toolbar => 'Easy' } %>
            </div>
            <div class="field textField">
                <%= f.label :content, "Текст" %>
                <%= f.text_area :content %>
                <%= cktext_area :conference, :content, :input_html => { :toolbar => 'Easy' } %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
```

i get two absolutely the same cktext_areas with russian text and one more simple text_area with english text(

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? It's not very beautiful and comfortable to have two different text areas

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a link to the batch translation gem you're using?

Comment: I'm using batch translation as a plugin, here is the link https://github.com/fidel/batch_translations

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cktext_area_tag` that works as text_area_tag does.

Comment: Your grammar here is very unclear. Can you clarify what you mean? (And, ideally, say why it would work?)